# How to extract 2nd dates of a column of strings?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a data frame with strings of dates:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~text,
  "...text...1/5/17 ...text... 12/26/18",
  "...text...3/1/19 ...text... 4/5/19",
  "...text...10/5/14 ...text...",
  "...text...5/5/16 ...text... 9/16/17",
  "...text...",
  "...text...2/22/20 ...text..."
)
```

I want to capture the 2nd dates of each string if it exists. Eventually I want to store the captured dates in a column of the data frame. I attempted using `stringr::str_extract` and it didn't seem to capture the 2nd dates even with the `group=2` parameter. (I'm pretty sure there is a better way to write the regex but I couldn't really think of one...)

```
str_extract(df$text, ".*(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+)|.*(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+)", group = 2)
```

output

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

My next attempt was to use `stringr::str_extract_all`. The resulting output is in a `list` and  it captures both the 1st and 2nd dates. I wrote a for loop to extract only the 2nd dates within each string.

```
str_extract_all(df$text, "(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+)") -> result

result2 <- rep(NA, length(result))

for (i in 1:length(result)){
  if(length(result[[i]] > 1)){
    result2[[i]] <- result[[i]][2]
  }
}

df$second_date <- result2
df
```

output

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  text                                 second_date
  <chr>                                <chr>      
1 ...text...1/5/17 ...text... 12/26/18 12/26/18   
2 ...text...3/1/19 ...text... 4/5/19   4/5/19     
3 ...text...10/5/14 ...text...         NA         
4 ...text...5/5/16 ...text... 9/16/17  9/16/17    
5 ...text...                           NA         
6 ...text...2/22/20 ...text...         NA
```

I find what I did very inefficient code and was wondering if there were any other ways to do the same task. I want to avoid using for loop at all if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only two things that look like dates, then you could use `str_extract_all()` to get both dates and then the second column would be the second date, if one exists.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~text,
  "...text...1/5/17 ...text... 12/26/18",
  "...text...3/1/19 ...text... 4/5/19",
  "...text...10/5/14 ...text...",
  "...text...5/5/16 ...text... 9/16/17",
  "...text...",
  "...text...2/22/20 ...text..."
)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.data.frame(str_extract_all(text, "\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+", simplify=TRUE))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(date) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(V1, V2), lubridate::mdy))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   text                                 V1         V2        
#>   <chr>                                <date>     <date>    
#> 1 ...text...1/5/17 ...text... 12/26/18 2017-01-05 2018-12-26
#> 2 ...text...3/1/19 ...text... 4/5/19   2019-03-01 2019-04-05
#> 3 ...text...10/5/14 ...text...         2014-10-05 NA        
#> 4 ...text...5/5/16 ...text... 9/16/17  2016-05-05 2017-09-16
#> 5 ...text...                           NA         NA        
#> 6 ...text...2/22/20 ...text...         2020-02-22 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your help. There is actually more text at the end of each string. ``......text...1/5/17 ...text... 12/26/18...text..``.  What regex should I use? I tried `[\\d\\/].*$` and it didnt really seem to work

Comment: @nightstand I just updated the answer, is that more what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to extract the second date. This regex grabs strings consisting of numbers and slashes, located at the end of the string, and following a `...text...`

```
second_date <- str_extract(df$text, '...text... ([0-9/]+$)',group = 1)
second_date
[1] "12/26/18" "4/5/19"   NA         "9/16/17"  NA         NA        

df$second_date <- second_date
df
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  text                                 second_date
  <chr>                                <chr>      
1 ...text...1/5/17 ...text... 12/26/18 12/26/18   
2 ...text...3/1/19 ...text... 4/5/19   4/5/19     
3 ...text...10/5/14 ...text...         NA         
4 ...text...5/5/16 ...text... 9/16/17  9/16/17    
5 ...text...                           NA         
6 ...text...2/22/20 ...text...         NA
```